# session flash data not working in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

there is a change password feature in my admin now before changing password i am validating by asking user to enter the username password again now if the user password is incorrect what i am doing is setting flash data and logging the user out. so when he comes to main login panel he should see the error now here is my code

the controller method

```
public function checkpassword(){
        $this->check_unique_id_from_db_for_secuity();
        $unique_id=base64_decode($this->uri->segment(3));
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $data['unique_id']=$unique_id;
        $status=$this->User_model->validate_user_loged_in_for_change_password($data);
        if($status){
            echo "true";
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('change_password_credentials_error',"Your Username/Password was incorect account was logged out for secutiry reasons!");
            echo "false";
            exit();
        }
    }
```

the ajax request

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo base_url()."User/checkpassword/".$this->uri->segment(3).""; ?>',
            data:{ "login_username" : $("#login_username").val(), "login_password" : $("#login_password").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data=="true"){
                    window.location.href="<?php echo base_url()."User/changepassword_view/".$this->uri->segment(3)."";?>";
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location.href="<?php echo base_url()."User/logout";?>";
                }
            }

        });
```

the php script on main login page

```
<?php
    if($this->session->flashdata('change_password_credentials_error')){?>
        <script>toastr["success"]("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('change_password_credentials_error')?>");</script>
    <?php } ?>
```

now the flash data is working just fine i am using it in many other pages but when i am using it with ajax somehow it is not being set! any help?

Comment: Flash data won't work until you redirect it. In AJAX No Way

Comment: so how can we implement a particular scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i get about flashdata from codeigniter doc:

> CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be available for the **next request**, and is then automatically cleared.

From above description, your **change_password_credentials_error** session will **only** available at "User/Logout" controller and cleared after controller processed. So, now after then redirected to Login Page the flashdata session will not available.

For this case, just clear login session after **$status** variable (else) checking, and then directly move / redirect user to main login page.

Comment: i like the idea but lets suppose i have this type of scenario!  so that means flash data cannot be set though ajax?